# Why, while creating an immutable class, are fields declared as private?

Tags: java, immutability, private, final

While creating an immutable class, all the fields are declared as final so that their value can’t be modified. This is okay, but why do we also declare them as private?

Comment: Do you know what `private` visibility is?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis if any member is private then it cant be accessed outside the class

Comment: The principle of encapsulation dictates that you expose to the outer world as little as necessary.

Comment: If the fields were mutable it wouldn't be a very good immutable class, would it?

Comment: @HotLicks OP is asking why they are `private`, not why they are not `final`. Being `final` makes them immutable, not being `private`.

Answer (score 4):

If the field is a reference to a mutable object, making it `final` will prevent the reference from being *rebound* to a different object. However, the object can still be modified, in effect side-stepping immutability of the containing object.

To prevent this, you can make the field `private` (if they can't see it, they can't modify it).

For example:

```
public class Order {
  public final List<OrderLine> order_lines = ...;
}
```

Here, anyone can come in and modify the order by adding/removing/modifying order lines, even though `order_lines` is `final`.

Comment: I think the question is about why they're `private`, not `final`.

Comment: >"if they can't see it, they can't modify it" - not true

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Elaborate.

Comment: @NPE Reflection can break `private`.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about reflection, and if we had to go around all day saying "immutable-not-counting-reflection" instead of just the one word "immutable" we wouldn't have time to get anything done.

Comment: @NPE  u said" being final will prevent the
reference from being rebound
to a different object. However,
the object can still be
modified,"
can u plz show me the ways by which inspite of being final the object can still be modified

Answer (score 0):

An immutable object can't change after being created, but that doesn't mean it necessarily has a simple implementation that should be exported to all clients.  As an example, take the `String` type, which uses a lot of crazy behind-the-scenes optimizations to maximize efficiency for common cases (for example, sharing a backing array when using `substring`).  By hiding all the fields of the class, the implementation can try to take advantage of time- or space-saving optimizations and mediate access to the stored data through the public interface.  If those fields were public, it would be difficult (if not impossible) to change the implementation after the fact.

In other words, immutability doesn't imply encapsulation or vice-versa.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am a newbie to programming...so i am not able to understand ur explanation like" hiding all
the fields of the class, the
implementation can try to
take advantage of time- or
space-saving optimizations"
can u please explain it by taking an another basic example :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person{
   public Date birthDate = new Date(615666470l); 
}
```

Then any person could have the birthDate updated from outside.

```
Person porfiriopartida = new Person();
porfiriopartida.birthDate=new Date(931199270);
```

If you provide a constructor with the needed starting attributes and then you only allow to get references to the values the that would work.

Also remember not to return the actual object in get methods (at least that are immutable themselves).