# In immutable class why fields are marked as private?

Tags: java, oop, field, private, immutability

What is the benefit of making fields private while creating an immutable class?

I have seen [why while creating immutable class, fields are declared as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19144062/2830834) but I didn't get understand anything from this post.

Can anybody please explain me the same?

Comment: I see some pretty solid answers to that question you cited.  The one that talks about the String class for example...  A Java `String` is immutable, but one of its `private final` fields refers to a _mutable_ `char[]` array.  The String methods never modify the array contents, but if the array reference were public, there would be nothing to stop other code from changing the value of a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to explain is with an example:

```
  public class Immutable {
     private final char[] state = "Hi Mom".getChars();
     
     public char[] getState() {
         return state.clone();
     }
  }
```

Here we have a properly encapsulated, immutable class.  Nothing can change the state (modulo nasty reflective tricks).

Now lets JUST change the access on the field:

```
  public class Immutable {
     public final char[] state = "Hi Mom".getChars();
     
     public char[] getState() {
         return state.clone();
     }
  }
```

Note we are still making the defensive copy in getState ... as before ... but now someone can do this:

```
  Immutable mu = new Immutable();
  mu.state[1] = 'o';
```

... and our supposedly immutable object's state has changed.

That is ONE reason why it is a good idea to keep the fields `private`.  (Obviously, this only applies to field whose types are mutable reference types.)

A SECOND reason is encapsulation.  Declaring fields as private hides implementation details, which reduces the risk of unwanted cross-coupling.  If I don't do this, then I (or some other programmer) might be tempted to write code that depends on the internals of `Immutable`.  That is going to lead to problems if I need to change them; e.g. changing the type of `state` to `String`.  Problems as in "lots more code to check / change".

A THIRD reason is that non-private (and particularly `public`) fields can be an impediment to subclassing.  If I declare a field as `public` then, the I can't *undeclare* it in a subclass.  If I want to hide the field or modify the behavior of the field in a subclass (by overriding) ... I can't.  By contrast, if the field is private and access is via instance methods, I can *override* those methods in subclasses.  Or I can choose to not use the field at all.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason for making final fields private is *binary compatibility*, and this actually holds true irrespective of whether the containing class is immutable or not.

> A class C is said to offer binary compatibility to classes X and Y
>   that use class C if class C can be refactored without having to
>   recompile classes X and Y.

You only need to worry about binary compatibility if you are developing a library to be used by software that is written by others and therefore you have no control over.  If you are in this situation, then you pretty much have to use full encapsulation, which means that you have to make all fields private and only access them via getters.

However, in the vast majority of cases, what we are developing is top-layer, self-contained application software, not libraries to be used by others.  So, in the vast majority of cases, there is no good reason to make final fields of immutable classes private, it is just a widely held misconception.  In a top-layer, self-contained application scenario you can always refactor everything and your IDE will accordingly refactor all references, so immutable classes do not need encapsulation.

Some of the answers suggest that if a field is not private, and it points to a mutable object, then someone might go and modify that mutable object, which is of course correct, but then we go into the philosophical question of what really is an immutable object.  Can an object still be called immutable if it contains mutable objects?  Is the mutability of an object dependent on the mutability of objects that it contains?

My rule is as follows:

There are two kinds of fields: *contained* and *referenced*, which can otherwise be thought of as *owned* and *unowned*. As an example, think of an `Employee` class: the name of the employee is contained/owned by the class, since each employee has their very own name.  However, the `Employee` class may also contain a reference to a `Department` class, and of course each employee does not have their very own department, so the department is a referenced/unowned field.

A contained/owned field like `Employee.name` must of course be final and immutable in order for the owning class (`Employee`) to be immutable. Such a field does not need to be private, unless we are aiming for binary compatibility.

A referenced/unowned field like `Employee.department` also needs to be final if the referring class (`Employee`) is to be immutable, but it does not have to be immutable, and its immutability does not affect the immutability of the referring class. Even in this case, (and unless we are aiming at binary compatibility,) a referenced/unowned field generally does not need to be private, because there is still no issue of encapsulation: we are not going to be making a defensive copy of an employee department, that would be nonsensical.

So, unless we are aiming for binary compatibility, then both in the case of contained/owned immutable fields and referenced/unowned fields (which can be either mutable or immutable,) the fields can stay `public final` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Defensive copies? And - by the way - there is a very good reason to make fields private: It is an implementation detail!

Comment: Defensive copies is precisely the kind of stuff that you save yourself from having to do by making extensive use of immutability.  You should not have to make a defensive copy of something; that something should be immutable to begin with.  As for the implementation detail myth, you know it does not hold right away when you see `private int x;` immediately followed by `public int getX();`

Comment: Ermm this is nonsense.  Making / returning a defensive copy of (say) an array only works if you can stop outsiders accessing the reference to the original array.  Unless the field is private, you can't stop them accessing the reference.

Comment: @MikeNakis This will surely become philosophical. But there is much to say about your comment (and your answer). 1) Defensive copies are the only way to expose references of mutable objects. 2) Even if having a `getX()` method, this could be implemented in many ways. The simplest and most used way is having a field with the same type. But - of course - you could have `private int y; public int getX() { return someComplicatedMath(y); }`. 3) Getters are OOP enemies, anyway. Immutable objects are not simple value holders where you often see private fields and publice getters for them.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Your #1 is repeating stuff that I have already anticipated. Your #2 is not only philosophical, but also off-topic: there is nothing about the encapsulation question which is specially applicable to the immutability question.

Answer (score 1):

An object that is referred to by a `public final` reference-type field *can* still be modified through that field. (What you *can't* do is change the field to refer to a different object.)

To disallow unwanted modifications, you need to make the field `private`.

Comment: @TheLostMind, Fields and methods and _objects_.   Or really, _variables_ and methods and objects; fields being just one of several different kinds of variable in Java.  A variable is not an object, and learning that seems to be one of the biggest conceptual hurdles that newbies face before they can become effective programmers.  I often say things like "`foo` can be modified" when what I really mean is, "the object to which `foo` _refers_ can be modified," but that's lazy of me, and it's misleading.  I try not to do it in this forum where so many newbies abide.

Comment: From the JLS:  "Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value."  In other words, the _variable_ (i.e., field or local or argument) can not be modified.  The JLS goes on:  "If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object."

Comment: Indeed I was not precise. Thanks @jameslarge. I've amended,

Answer (score 1):

```
final class A{
   final List l = new ArrayList(); 
}
```

Suppose you have list, and you made this list as `final` it's reference not modified at all.

But this list is easily accessible to outer classes and they are easily modify it's contents.

so prevent that we have to add `private` access specifier.

Answer (score 0):

public fields can be accessed from any class anywhere and modified. But making *fields private and final* and using *constructor injection / defensive copies*, you ensure that the *class is completely immutable*.

Comment: OP is asking why `public final` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @B.Dalton - Making the field *private* makes sure that your field is *not visible* to the outside world. Its simple, you can't modify what you can't see. Next it follows *encapsulation*.

Comment: I know that, TheLostMind. I understand why encapsulation and data-hiding is A Good Thing (TM). I'm simply noting that your answer doesn't explain why immutable objects cannot have public final fields and remain immutable. To be clear, the answer is that once callers can access a class's publicly accessible final fields, callers may modify the objects that they references. Immutable classes often want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Non-private fields may still be read-accessed - and if that field is an object, mutable operations on that object may be invoked.

Making the fields private will prevent this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll use `public` field other objects will be able to change state of your "almost-immutable" object which will break encapsulation and make it a mutable object.